# How to centralizing IAP in main.swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am trying to put all my IAP code in a class called iapController and put it in main.swift Here is the code:

```
class iapController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

var product:SKProduct!

class func offerUnlockLevels() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    getProductInfo()
    let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment (product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("inside purchased")
                self.openAllLevels()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break
            case .Failed:
                println("inside failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break
            case .Restored:
                println("inside restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}


func openAllLevels() {
    println("inside openAllLevels()")
    unlockAllLevelsButton.hidden = true
    for var i=0; i<20; i++ {
        levelCollectionButtons[i].setBackgroundImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
    }
}

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    let products = response.products
    println(products)
    if products.count != 0
    {
        product = products[0] as SKProduct
        println(product.localizedTitle + "\n" + product.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getProductInfo() { //Checks if user can make IAP (has itunes account)
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "Zero.UnlockAllLevels") //Hold our product ID
        let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
}

}
```

Note that I made offerUnlockLevels() a class level function because I want to call it from other view controllers. However I am getting error: Type iapController.Type does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'

If I dont make it a class level function, I am unable to call this function from within other viewcontroller calsses. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I dont make it a class level function, I am unable to call this function from within other view controller calsses

Certainly you can. You can call view controller instance methods from other view controllers. You can call *any* instance method on an instance of of *any* class, as long as it is not private. That is what instance methods are *for*.

For example, when you say

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(someVC, animated:true)
```

...you are calling an instance method of a view controller - the navigation controller is a view controller, and `pushViewController:animated:` is an instance method, not a class method.

So, take off the `class` designation and let `offerUnlockLevels` be an instance method, and you will be able to call it on any instance of your `iapController` class.

Comment: However, it is far from clear to me to why you want this to be a UIViewController subclass. Why don't you just make it an NSObject subclass? It evidently isn't controlling any view; it's just a packet of StoreKit-related functionality. It almost seems as if you don't really quite understand what classes and instances _are_. If that's the case, I suggest you stop and get an understanding of that, since you can't do object-oriented programming otherwise.

Comment: from within other viewcontroller class (LevelsViewController) I called self.iapController!.offerUnlockLevels() but it is giving error 'LevelsViewController' does not have a member named iapController.

Comment: Well, that is because it doesn't. To call an instance method, you need to have created (get ready for it) _an instance_. You need to make an instance of iapController, and then, if you want to use the calling syntax you are using there, you would also need to assign it to an `iapController` property of LevelsViewController.

Comment: However, I don't understand why you don't just put all the SK-related functionality in the app delegate. That is the usual place. It has the clear advantage that this is an instance that will always exist. Or, if LevelsViewController will always exist, then just put the SK-related functionality there, rather than introducing an extra object / class into the story.

Comment: thank you, instance solved the problem. i m new to it hence the hick-ups :) thanks for your patience.